# (Google Cloud) Is there any way to remedy a very large bill that has accrued due to a mistaken operation for several hours?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, translate

We are a small company using the cloud, spending tens of thousands to around a million won per month. Due to an erroneous operation in Google Pubsub, there were a very large number of requests, resulting in an unintended charge of approximately 7 million won for the Translate service.

We verified the issue and immediately stopped the subscription. However, it appears that all remaining processes internally were executed, resulting in a significant bill

Is there any way we can receive at least a partial refund or deduction for this?

I was aware of the issue and had immediately canceled the subscription. However, upon later review, I noticed that charges continued to accrue afterward. I would like to know if there is any way to receive partial reimbursement or relief from these charges, please.

Comment: Your only option is to negotiate with your Google cloud representative (sales, CE,...). A friend of mine likes to say: "if you go on vacation with the light switched on in the bathroom, you won't call the electricity company to ask for a refund."